# How to open an old MVC project moved on another computer?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have reinstalled my windows and I had an old project in Visual Studio MVC 5.
Now when I try to open it I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyusC.png)

Comment: Looks like you are missing a reference to this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a .NET project package which's name is CodeAnalysis.Csharp. 
Try to install it through NuGet console package manager. Write the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
```

If you already have that package, but older one, you might wanna do this:

```
Update-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
```

How to arrive to the console package manager?

On visual studio click:

Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Package Manager Console.

Hope it helps.